# PHP/MySQL contact list

Tags: php, mysql, list, contacts

I want to create contact list [like on facebook](https://www.facebook.com/messages) using php and mysql. I have table messages (values: ID | From | To | message_body | date | status), but i don't know how to get message sender id (value "from") just one time. Anyone can help?

Comment: What do you mean by "just one time"? Can you show your code and describe where it is failing?

Comment: I don't write code for this yet. I have data on database like this:
ID | From | To | message_body | date | status
1  | 4    | 8  | hello        | now()| 1
2  | 8    | 4  | hi           | now()| 1

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. And we really need to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: So.. I have table messages. In table messages i have 6 columns, (ID | From | To | message_body | date | status) and i want to get list of all "from" ids where  "to" column is user id (session), but i want to get this id (from) only one time (don't repeat). It's to be list of users, who sent messages to now logged user (instant messenger). Do you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what I think you're looking for...

```
SELECT DISTINCT `From`
FROM `messages`
WHERE `To` = `current_user_id`
```